# Low quality auto-flag - why doesn't a comment count as an action?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, low-quality-posts

Recently, I have seen "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." in the review queue. It was a self answer posted few days ago. Self answers are usually relevant and really answers the question. The one I'm talking about was, but it was also so short that it wasn't clear. "But I know what I mean" situation, surely salvageable.

I wasn't knowledgeable enough to edit. It was too good to recommend deletion, but not good enough to click "looks good". And it was the only answer, so deleting it would hide the only hint from future visitors.

I think that by commenting to the author I did the right thing, and I don't really despair at one review lost on my way to the badge, but I just wonder - are situations like this so rare, that it isn't worth it to count a comment as a review in this queue?

Comment: I agree that "looks good" is unimaginably poor wording

Comment: @RichardTingle I'm not saying it is ;) It was the first time it got me confused after months of access to the queue. So maybe that's not really a bad wording, but atypical situation? One situation in dozens might be not worth rewording a button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The very low quality queue is there to delete the very lowest quality of content.  From that queue "looks good" simply means, "this isn't so bad that it should be deleted".  It doesn't mean, "this is a great post".  You can both downvote a post and "looks good" it in the queue, if it's bad, but not bad enough that you think it should be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

> ... are situations like this so rare, that it isn't worth it to count a comment as a review in this queue?

Not so rare, while searching for duplicates I came across your question. [Bump] :)

On our Operations Research site we have a question: "[Is a “multistep” or “multiphase” Newsvendor model possible?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/2922/51)", to which a new user (for their first post) replied: "Check the (S,s) policy and the related inventory policies.".

The moderator and myself don't necessarily disagree with the answer, only that it would be improved if it were longer. We were both writing our comments at the same time.

[image: VLQ Answer]

Since they are a new user we want to be welcoming and allow them to improve their answer, which they are likely capable of doing without assistance. So the choices are to: "go into the question and vote", "go into the question and comment", or one of the four buttons.

We seem to be in agreement that only commenting is appropriate. I did not choose "[Skip]" and so the review remains in the queue (our new site has a relatively low amount of traffic, and presumably other users agree with our action).

What we **really need** is a '[Temporary Skip]' button, where this would be removed from the queue for either 48 hours or until they visit **any** site and read or ignore the comments - whichever comes first.

If there's an even better course of action that would make a better answer. What ultimately ended up happening was that the too short answer was converted to a [comment on the question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2922/is-a-multistep-or-multiphase-newsvendor-model-possible#comment3168_2922) and a moderator provided their own answer to the question; hopefully the new user doesn't feel circumlocuted.

A temporary skip respects the new user, allows an optional comment (it would be a good idea to make at least one comment mandatory), and if a few users agreed (or one Mod or Gold Tag) then the question or answer could re-enter the queue (and remind everyone) after giving the new user a chance.

Simply skipping obligates you to remember all your skips or to rely on other reviewers when there may only be a few. Because our queues are so empty we can simply exit the queue after commenting, there is no *next* item to be reviewed (yet).

Comment: *"Since they are a new user we want to be welcoming and allow them to improve their answer..."* Yes, fortunately, they can still edit while the answer is deleted. So what you should do is delete the answer, just as you would for all other non-answers.

Comment: @CodyGray I've decided to comment and don't have the power to delete by hammer. Also the site's moderator's decision is explained in the answer, and how it is there. Some places are friendly and easy going, helping new users write their question, some are not. A dozen downvotes, comments, and a deleted question isn't the greeting we plan for their return - and I said that the answer isn't incorrect.